Unable to post the markdown string to hygraph api
I am trying to post the data to the Hygraph from dotnet core application.
I have successfully able to post other data but while posting the content which is of rich text type, it is giving me error as:

I have tried to send a markdown string.

could not transform richText: Values should be an array of objects
containing raw rich text values

 // Create the mutation
 var mutation = new GraphQLHttpRequest
 {
     Query = @"
     mutation($data: BlogListCreateInput!) {
         createBlogList(data: $data) {                      
                 id 
         }
     }",

     Variables = new
     {
         data = new
         {

             title,
             description,
             isFeatured,
             content = new
             {
                 markdown = content
             }
         }
     }
 };

 // Send the mutation to create the data
 var response = await graphQLClient.SendMutationAsync<dynamic>(mutation);

What is the workaround for this?
